# Yii CDN Asset Management

Tags: php, yii, composer-php

I am trying to use this extension https://github.com/2amigos/yii-cdn-asset-management-library in order to publish my assets to Amazon S3.

I installed it using Composer and I can confirm that the files are there. According to the documentation, the next step is to modify my Yii configuration file (I modified main.php and console.php) and put the necessary information in the components section. I already did that.

In order to publish the assets, I needed to run the following code:

```
./yiic S3 --manager=cdnManager publish --userVersionCache=1
```

However, yiic cannot seem to locate the S3Command.php file. I get no such file or directory errors because of that. Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: put that file to your commands directory?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that. I already did that. It's visible in the list of commands in yiic. Of course, it would be better if there's another way than copying the file manually to the commands directory since there might be updates on the file.